# CodeIgniter Active Record collation

Tags: codeigniter, collate

I am working with CodeIgniter and want to return some values using a distinct query, I am not able to change the collation in the database itself, and can not do so in the config either, as I am changing somebody else's code.

Is there a way to collate within a query using Active Record? So far I have tried:

`$this->db->select('fieldName COLLATE utf8_bin');`

I have also attempted to use `$this->db->collator_set_default` to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Try to read over the manual
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

In the default connection array you can find fields

```
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
```

Might go also with a code while the query is run

```
$this->db->query("SET NAMES 'latin1'");
$this->db->insert('table_name', $data);
```

Comment: Sorry, I have stated that I can not edit the config, this includes database.php, thank you anyway :)

Comment: Uhm I see. You can try like $this->db->query("SET NAMES 'latin1'");
and then your query $this->db->insert('table_name', $data);, might help

Comment: I am not inserting into the database, I am trying to select without being case-insensitive, which means that I have to collate

For example with a table that contains "this" and "This", `SELECT DISTINCT name COLLATE utf8_bin FROM table` would return both "this" and "This", whereas without the COLLATE, it would only return "this" or "This"

Comment: Give it a try or maybe try to convert the output with http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php idk what can help:)